# What should I expect from a developers guide?

Tags: development-process

I'm willing, with some friends, to make a developers guide for an open source point of sale written in Java.

The thing is I have never written anyone and so I don't know exactly what to put in there to meet standards. I'm thinking about putting UML, and using Java doc but still I don't know what are the expectations of developers towards a developers guide.

How can we say a developer's guide is truly worth?

Comment: Do you contribute some code to the project? And what project is it? What approximate size, how many contributors....

Comment: Yes, I do want to contribute code to it. The software is  a fork of openbravoPOS. I'm a newbie at programming. I'm not sure of what programmers expect to see in a doc said for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good developer's guide should be able to guide developers who want to use your product/library.

- It should give them an overview of *what* the product/library is.
- It should have an *overview* of any special concepts necessary to use it. For example, if you have a library creates formatted documents of a very specific type, an overview of the document structure might be a good idea. If it's a graphics rendering library, an overview of the rendering pipeline would be useful.
- It should contain a complete listing of all *public* components (classes, functions, whatever) that a developer *could* use. Javadoc can probably generate all of this.
- Examples of common uses of programming with the product are also very good to have, including working code examples.
- Special instructions for setup/getting started with development.

One way to think about it might be to put yourself in your target users' shoes and ask yourself what *you* would want to see if you knew *nothing* about this product, and suddenly had to write code for it.

Comment: You forgot about code samples.

Answer (score 2):

I would put in such a guide an architecture overview, and coding rules (like [these](https://gcc.gnu.org/codingconventions.html)). Some building instructions (like [this)](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/), some "contribute how-to" (like [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/contribute.html)).

<sup>I gave an example thru links related to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to explain what I mean. I don't claim it is the best example.</sup>

I'm not sure that UML will bring a lot (and then you should have to maintain the UML).

Particularily if your software is a library or is extensible via plugins, give some code examples (how to use that library, or of a typical plugin).

The most important is to stay in sync with the code base.

Comment: What are "coding rules?"  What's a "contribute how-to?"

Comment: Edited my answer by linking to GCC examples.

Answer (score 2):

Some of things I would look for in a library or program:

1. What it does, and what is it's intended purpose.  You said it's a point of sale system, but that still doesn't really tell me what all features the product has.
2. A setup guide so that I can get the system up and running.  Bonus points if you give me an automated process that will do this for me so I don't have spend a lot of time in configuration.
3. Any domain concepts I might need to understand the system.  A glossary of terms can be helpful.
4. A specification would also be good.  Knowing that a system does Foo because it's supposed to and not as a happy accident is helpful.
5. Code examples of its usage or ways to extend it.  If it's extensible or able to be integrated, then an example extension\integration is very instructive on how I might utilize the system.
6. Finally, architecture diagrams, and an overview of the codebase(s).

Comment: +1 just for bullet 5.  Code samples, code samples, code samples.  If I have code samples, I can figure the rest out.